Movie with insects attacking humans
I saw a movie long time back in which scientific experiments were being conducted on a particular class of insects, which went wrong and the insects started attacking people and eating them.
I remember that these insects did not attack those who ate organic food. I think, in the end, the entire science facility was destroyed by the main protagonist (who used to grow food organically) by an airplane crash that killed his wife's father (who was on the team of scientists conducting experiments).

By a long time back, how old do you mean? Is it a color or B&W movie? Do you have an approximate time-frame when it was released? Was it a Hollywood film or maybe an independent? Did it have any recognizable stars? Any other info will help us help you.

Sounds like Locusts: The 8th Plague with Julie Benz. From Wiki:

a 2005 natural-horror film... about a group of farmers and scientists that battle a swarm of flesh-eating locusts that have escaped from a secret genetics laboratory in Idaho.

The protagonist (Dan Cortese) runs a business for organic pesticide and at some point isn't attacked because he only eats organic food. I vaguely recall that it ends in a similar manner, with guilt-ridden scientist Jeff Fahey (who plays Julie Benz's father) setting off a bomb in an act of self-sacrifice and the protagonist's crop-duster figures into this somehow.
